# undefined variable on codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

I have a project in which is develop in codeigniter.

The project is like this:

```
-root

--controller 

---Slider.php

--models

---My_data.php

--views

---slider_view.php

---giris.php
```

#### Slider.php

```
public function manset_al(){
    $title['title']='manşet listesi';
    $this->load->model('My_data');
    $data['manset']= $this->My_data->get_manset();
    $this->load->view('slider_view' ,$data);
}
```

#### My_data.php code is;

```
public function get_manset() {
    //  $sorgu = 
    //  mysql_query("select * from manset, haberler 
    //  where manset.onay='1' and manset.link=haberler.id and haberler.onay='1'
    //  order by haberler.id desc");
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('manset as man, haberler as hab');
    $this->db->where('man.link=hab.id');
    $this->db->where('hab.onay=1');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return $query->result();
    }
```

#### slider_view.php code is:

```
foreach($manset as $row){ 
    $baslik     =$row->baslik;
    $icerik     =$row->icerik;
    $link       =$row->link;
    $img_path   =$row->img_path;
    $giris      =$row->giris;
    $cikis      =$row->cikis;
         echo ' 

        <div>
           <a href="?pid='.$link.'">  <img data-u="image" src="'.$img_path.'"/></a>
          <div data-u="thumb"> <a href="?pid='.$link.'">  <h5 style="color:white; margin:10px;">'.$baslik.' </h5> </a></div>  
        </div>';
       }
```

Now when i called

```
http//example.com/index.php/Slider/manset_al
```

every think is ok - the slider is running.

But when i get the slider in `giris.php` with this code;

```
$this->load->view('slider_view');
```

it's not run and say:  undefined variable manset;

how can ı fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a file name and line number beside the "undefined variable manset;" notice?

Comment: yes line number is 121

Comment: Fine. If you launch your text editor, load the file and browse to line 121 you should be able to find the line of code that's potentially wrong. You may edit the question and share the information with us.

Comment: the line is this. I think it is not wrong.

foreach($manset as $row){ 

        $baslik     =$row->baslik;

        $icerik     =$row->icerik;

        $link       =$row->link;

        $img_path   =$row->img_path;

        $giris      =$row->giris;

        $cikis      =$row->cikis;

             echo '  some text
          
         ';
        
           }

Answer (score 0):

We're missing some details to quickly solve this one: namely, how is giris.php called, exactly?  Without those details I can only give a general answer.

This error means that you are trying to access data in your template file that you haven't passed to the templating system.  For instance, in your controller (Slider.php) you pass data off to the templates here:

```
$this->load->view('slider_view' ,$data);
```

The `$data` is the important part: codeigniter takes every entry in that array and creates a variable in the template system whos name corresponds to the name of each key.  Therefore, `foreach( $manset as $row )` works because `$data` has a key named `manset` that has each row in it.  You can see that in `giris.php` you are specifically **not** sending any data to the template:

```
$this->load->view('slider_view');
```

Notice the lack of a second parameter.  Of course your file structure implies that `giris.php` is itself a view file, which means that whatever controller method that called `giris.php` needs to be the one sending data out to the view.  So generally, that is the answer: whatever controller is ultimately calling `giris.php` needs to be sending the slider information out to the templating system, but isn't.  Without more details on how `giris.php` is actually called, that is as specific as I can get.

Comment: so, how can we fix it?

Comment: Post more code.  In particular, information about how your application gets to `giris.php` in the first place.